# jQuery - Accordion Effect on a Table

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-accordion

I'm having difficulty implementing an accordion effect on three different tables using jQuery and I could use some assistance. Right now it works o.k. When I click on the header rows the subsequent rows show, but I'd like some type of animation. I'd also like to have the first table show completely, but I'm a newbie and this is above my head.

Here is my HTML.

```
<table class="research">
                <tbody>
                    <tr class="accordion">
                        <td colspan="3">This is the header</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Research</td>
                        <td>Description</td>
                        <td>Partner</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</td>
                        <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</td>
                        <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>

            <table class="research">
                <tbody>
                    <tr class="accordion">
                        <td colspan="3">This is the header</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Research</td>
                        <td>Description</td>
                        <td>Partner</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</td>
                        <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</td>
                        <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>

            <table class="research">
                <tbody>
                    <tr class="accordion">
                        <td colspan="3">This is the header</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Research</td>
                        <td>Description</td>
                        <td>Partner</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</td>
                        <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</td>
                        <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

And here is my jQuery:

```
$(function() {
  $(".research tr:not(.accordion)").hide();
  $(".research tr:first-child").show();
  $(".research tr.accordion").click(function(){
  $(this).nextAll("tr").toggle();
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

```
$(function() {
  $(".research tr:not(.accordion)").hide();
  $(".research tr:first-child").show();
    
  $(".research tr.accordion").click(function(){
      $(this).nextAll("tr").fadeToggle(500);
  }).eq(0).trigger('click');
});
```

`.fadeToggle(500);` animates the display of the elements rather than just showimg/hiding them.

`.eq(0).trigger('click');` triggers a click on the first header so that it's content will be shown when the page loads.

A cool effect to use is `slideUp()` and `slideDown()` but it appears as though you can't use them with table rows.

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Xqk3m/

### Update

You can also optimize your code a bit by caching the `.research` selector:

```
$(function() {
    var $research = $('.research');
    $research.find("tr").not('.accordion').hide();
    $research.find("tr").eq(0).show();
    
    $research.find(".accordion").click(function(){
        $(this).siblings().fadeToggle(500);
    }).eq(0).trigger('click');
});
```

In this example I also removed all the string selectors in favor of function selections (e.g. used `.not()` instead of `:not()`). The functions for DOM traversal are faster than putting selectors in a string.

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Xqk3m/1/

### Update

And last but not least, if you want it to be an accordion where when you open one section the rest close, here's a solution:

```
$(function() {
    var $research = $('.research');
    $research.find("tr").not('.accordion').hide();
    $research.find("tr").eq(0).show();
    
    $research.find(".accordion").click(function(){
        $research.find('.accordion').not(this).siblings().fadeOut(500);
        $(this).siblings().fadeToggle(500);
    }).eq(0).trigger('click');
});
```

`$research.find('.accordion').not(this).siblings().fadeOut(500);` is the important part, it selects all the `.accordion` elements except for the one that was clicked, then finds the siblings of all the `.accordion` elements selected and hides them.

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Xqk3m/2/

Comment: Hi Jasper, 

Nice solution. :-)

I am trying to get it to work on a dynamic table My table is within a DIV with id="mapcanvas"

$("#mapcanvas").empty();$("#mapcanvas").css("height", "auto");$("#mapcanvas").html("<table width=\"100%\" border=\"0\" class=\"research\"> etc.

The table shows correctly - with all the TR's visible, and clicking them no longer works.

A hint as to what should be done to fix it would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks Jasper. I worked it out. I should have put your code after the ;$("#mapcanvas").html( ...); 

No drinking enough coffee, it would seem

Answer (score 2):

i added a fade effect. Check it - http://jsfiddle.net/XE6AG/1/

```
    $(function() {
      $(".research tr:not(.accordion)").hide();
      $(".research tr:first-child").show();
      $(".research tr.accordion").click(function(){
      $(this).nextAll("tr").fadeToggle();
       });
    });
```

this one is faster - http://jsfiddle.net/XE6AG/2/

```
    //this is fast
    $(function() {
      $(".research tr:not(.accordion)").hide();
      $(".research tr:first-child").show();
      $(".research tr.accordion").click(function(){
      $(this).nextAll("tr").fadeToggle("fast");
       });
    });
```

this one is really really slow - http://jsfiddle.net/XE6AG/3/

```
    //this is fast
    $(function() {
      $(".research tr:not(.accordion)").hide();
      $(".research tr:first-child").show();
      $(".research tr.accordion").click(function(){
      $(this).nextAll("tr").fadeToggle("fast");
       });
    });
```

you could also add easing to it for example - http://jsfiddle.net/XE6AG/4/.

Comment: Thanks very much, Andrew! Appreciate it. Is there a way you can tell me how to have just the first table display in its entirety while hiding the other two? I want the user to see some content and not just the headers.