# HTML / CSS: Same table-cell width across rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html-table

I have this table that includes details about its items on the right and I need to have all the cells in a column of the exact same width as the longest one, just like in the screenshot below:

[image]

This works if I use a regular table, but now I need to add an accordion function on top of it, so when I click on a row, the row's associated content will slide down from under each one.

The only way to add those content divs between table rows is to wrap them in `<tr>` tags, which don't work with the `slideDown()` and `slideUp()` effects.

Now I recreated the table in a fiddle using `<dl>` tags, hoping to solve this using CSS somehow, but no such luck. Here's the link: http://jsfiddle.net/bbDYX/ - everything is working properly, except for the width issue.

The only solution I can think of now is going through each table-cell on each of the right hand columns with JavaScript and setting their width to the same value as the highest width cell. But I want to avoid that if I can.

Any ideas?

Comment: yea why not just add the content div in a td with colspan and slide the content div inside of the td, using a normal table

Comment: Why not use the table then and apply an accordion effect rather than hacking up a solution in which you take tabular data and display it in `dl` and `dt`s ? See this SO as an example of applying an accordion effect to a table [**jQuery - Accordion Effect on a Table**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9026867/jquery-accordion-effect-on-a-table) It even has a jsFiddle example in the answer doing exactly what you want. Click row - show details

Comment: In these cases, I usually *don't* use the jQueryUI widgets (in fact, I never use them); instead I write my own to suit my needs (for example, expand/collapse table rows); it's just a few lines of codes using jQueryUI animations and the whole thing benefits greatly from it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what you need: [myjsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BPxS5/)

**css:**

```
.con1
{
width:100%;
height:50px;
background-color:#F3E2A9; 
}
```

**Html:**

```
<table border='0' cellspacing='3' width='100%'>
<tr bgcolor='lightblue'>
    <td><a href='#' class='open1' >Item</a></td>
    <td>detail 1</td>
    <td>detail 2</td>
    <td>detail 3</td>
</tr>
<tr><td colspan='4'><div class='con1'>con1</div></td></tr>
<tr bgcolor='lightblue'>
    <td><a href='#' class='open1' >Item</a></td>
    <td>detail 1</td>
    <td>detail 2</td>
    <td>detail 3</td>
</tr>
<tr><td colspan='4'><div class='con1'>con1</div></td></tr>
<tr bgcolor='lightblue'>
    <td><a href='#' class='open1' >Item</a></td>
    <td>detail 1</td>
    <td>detail 2</td>
    <td>detail 3</td>
</tr>
<tr><td colspan='4'><div class='con1'>con1</div></td></tr>
</table>
```

**Script:**

```
$('.con1').hide();
$('.open1').click(function() {
    $(this).parent().parent().next().find('.con1').slideToggle();    
    return false;        
});
```

have fun styling it...
(tested)

Comment: I actually tried this approach yesterday, but I was so tired, I couldn't figure out how to get rid of the extra space the hidden `<tr>`s were causing. The space was caused by the `border-spacing` on the `<table>`. Ugh, my downvote was well deserved. Next time I'll have a nap before asking questions. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can't slide up the `<tr>` tag, but you can slide up the `<td>` tags. Not sure if this would work for you, but worth considering...

```
$("#somerow").find("td").slideToggle();
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, as I stated in a comment, I would keep the table and create a "custom widget" for the accordion-like effect.

The thing would be very simple, using jQuery UI animations etc.

For example, you can create a basic "description toggle" with just four lines of code:

```
$('.mytable .description').hide();
$('.mytable').on('click', '.title', function(){
    $(this).next('.description').toggle();
});
```

(of course then you can customize the .toggle() by adding effect type, duration, ...)

Here it is a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/JAmFh/