# Create table with hidden info between rows

Tags: jquery, asp.net, .net, frames

I'm trying to create a table that when a row is selected more information about the items in that row will be displayed without needing to load to a new page.  My thoughts were to use a jquery to display this frame when clicked.

I'm new to this so I'm not even sure how to phrase the question and web searches haven't pointed me to tutorial/answer.  Any help would be appreciated.

Edit: Rather than show code, since I don't know what I'm looking for, here's a screen shot of an example from my bank.  The table displays payee information and dates of previous payments.  But by clicking on the the "+Show Payment Summary" link more information about that payee is displayed.

Comment: Can you please edit the question with what you have got so far? It is very hard to help without specific code snippets.

Comment: There are too many ways, with hidden div or span, with input controls that also post back their values, with other elements place them on attributes... be more specific to get more clear answer.

Comment: I think what you're looking for can be achieved with `jquery ui accordion`, check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9026867/jquery-accordion-effect-on-a-table

Comment: @G.Mendes - that might be a solution I'm looking for thanks.
Aristos, this is somewhat what I need; a starting point of a list of elements/solutions to research.  I'm just getting back into coding and am not familiar with all of the tools out there.

Comment: I don't have enough reputation points yet to actually post that image.