# Exclude multiple elements in .not, including $this

Tags: jquery, html

The following hides all table rows, excluding rows with class `.accordion` or `.course_header`.

```
  $('#course_list').find("tr").not('.accordion, .course_header').hide();
```

How do I exclude `$(this).next("tr")` table row as well?  That is assuming `this` is a `tr` that was just clicked.

**Full details**

I'm working on a table with an accordion effect using [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9026901/193210).  With the solution as-is, if I click on a row, its child stays expanded.  Notice when you click a row [in the jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f8ceLLju/1/), it expands the child correctly, but I want it to close the child when I click that same row again.

What I have currently:

```
var $course_list = $('#course_list');
$course_list.find("tr").not('.accordion, .course_header').hide();
$course_list.find("tr").eq(0).show();

$course_list.find(".accordion").click(function(){
   $course_list.find("tr").not('.accordion, .course_header').hide();
   $(this).next("tr").fadeToggle('fast');
});
```

Here is the table layout:

```
<table id="course_list">
  <thead>
    <tr class="course_header">
      <th>Date</th>
      <th>Presenter</th>
      <th>Title</th>
     </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="accordion">
      <td>09.26.14</td>
      <td>Arthur Dent</td>
      <td>Example Course</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="4">
        COURSE DETAILS GO HERE
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="accordion">
      <td>09.30.14</td>
      <td>Winston Smith</td>
      <td>Another Example</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="4">
        COURSE DETAILS GO HERE
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to append it to the chain:

```
var next = $(this).next("tr");
$course_list.find("tr").not('.accordion, .course_header').not(next).hide();
```

Comment: Your solution seems to work for what I asked, but now I just realized I'm asking the wrong question :).  I'm actually wanting to ignore `$(this).next("tr")`.

Comment: Turns out your solution works for that specific question as well: `.not($(this).next("tr"))`.  Can you update your answer with that and I'll accept it?  You definitely put me on the right track.

Comment: yeah, just came with the solution above :)